# How to resume spotify player playback after interrupt when app is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I have an app which plays Spotify track. It works perfectly when app moves to background but when it get interrupted by 'call' or 'iOS pop-ups' it stops playing.
I have added `Required background modes` to `App plays audio` in **.plist**.
How to resume playback when interruption ended while app is in **background**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used audio interruption callbacks.

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, interruptionListenerCallback,self);
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

And after receiving interruption call play/pause method of playback manager.

```
void interruptionListenerCallback (void *inUserData, UInt32 interruptionState)
{
// This callback, being outside the implementation block, needs a reference
//to the AudioPlayer object
CustomPlayerView *controller = (__bridge CustomPlayerView *) inUserData;

if (interruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption)
{
   [controller.playbackManager setIsPlaying:NO];
}
else if (interruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption)
{
   [controller.playbackManager setIsPlaying:YES];
}
}
```